# pass string from one method to another android

Tags: android, string, methods

I'm new to android development, and starting to learn some things...
I want to know how to implement one thing that I know is very basic, but I cannot find a way to do it with my actual knowledge of Android programming. Been trying for hours now and no results after all! I found lots of questions here on stack overflow with people asking the same thing, I've tried a lot of them, but no success after all!

I wrote the following code, with 2 methods (vo2maxCalculo and shareIt), the "share it" method should get the value from the MSG1 variable and insert this value into the "shareBody" string, so the user can share it via email, etc..

How can I do that?

Thank you very much!

---

```
        public void vo2maxCalculo(View v) {
        float minutos2;
        double calculo2;

        EditText minutos1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutos);
        TextView resultado5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vo2max12Resultado);


        minutos2 = Float.parseFloat(minutos1.getText().toString());

        calculo2 = 33 + 0.17 * (minutos2 - 1955) / 15;
        String msg1 = String.format("%.2f", calculo2);
        resultado5.setText(msg1);


    }

    public void shareIt(View v) {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = String.format("The result is:", msg1);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Final Result");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you want an extra parameter (I'm not sure if that's what you're asking)

Comment: Are these methods a click listener defined in xml? If yes then I shall have to give you another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable out side both the scopes like this

```
String msg1; //Like this
public void vo2maxCalculo(View v) {
    float minutos2;
    double calculo2;

    EditText minutos1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutos);
    TextView resultado5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vo2max12Resultado);


    minutos2 = Float.parseFloat(minutos1.getText().toString());

    calculo2 = 33 + 0.17 * (minutos2 - 1955) / 15;
    msg1 = String.format("%.2f", calculo2); //Set it in here like this
    resultado5.setText(msg1);


}

public void shareIt(View v) {

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

    //Can still use it in here as long as the other method got called first
    String shareBody = String.format("The result is: %s", msg1);

    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Final Result");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

}
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately it does not worked... Let me try to explain how my app works: It is a very basic app that calculates Vo2Max, there is an activity with one "EditText" where the user inserts the value, then, when he presses the "Calculate" button, the method "vo2maxCalculo" is called, the calculation is done and then the result is displayed in a TextView. There is also one "Share" button, that invokes the method "shareIt". My idea was to let the user share the result of the calculation via email, etc... And that's what I can not make work.

Comment: Well, Not an error... It just printed the message "the result is:", without the result itself. Like its not getting the value from "msg1"

Comment: I figured out your error. In your String.format() you are missing a %s try the above code again and see if it works.

Comment: FANTASTIC!!! IT WORKED!! Thank you VERY MUCH SuNny_sYeD, and thank you all that helped me a lot in solving this problem and improving my knowledge!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly then this is the solution. Also I am sure in almost every programming language this is done like this.

**Both methods appear to be click listeners: Use this only if they are not**

```
public String vo2maxCalculo(View v) { // changed here
    float minutos2;
    double calculo2;

    EditText minutos1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutos);
    TextView resultado5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vo2max12Resultado);


    minutos2 = Float.parseFloat(minutos1.getText().toString());

    calculo2 = 33 + 0.17 * (minutos2 - 1955) / 15;
    String msg1 = String.format("%.2f", calculo2);
    resultado5.setText(msg1);

    return msg1; // added this

}

public void shareIt(View v) {

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    //String shareBody = String.format("The result is:", vo2maxCalculo(v)); // Why String.format???
    String shareBody = "The result is:" + vo2maxCalculo(v); // Replace this
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Final Result");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

}
```

**Both methods appear to be click listeners: Use this if they really are**

```
String msg1 = ""; // Added this
public void vo2maxCalculo(View v) {
    float minutos2;
    double calculo2;

    EditText minutos1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutos);
    TextView resultado5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vo2max12Resultado);

    minutos2 = Float.parseFloat(minutos1.getText().toString());

    calculo2 = 33 + 0.17 * (minutos2 - 1955) / 15;
    msg1 = String.format("%.2f", calculo2); // Edited this
    resultado5.setText(msg1);
}
```

And no change in the other method

Comment: Not sure but I'm guessing these both are onClick methods by the way they are set up so `String` would be an invalid return type. Again, the question is unclear so maybe not

Comment: If both are click listeners from xml then this whole concept is wrong! Lets see what OP has to say about it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! I want to get the value from string "msg1" that is in method "vo2maxCalculo" and insert this value into string "shareBody" in method "shareIt"

Comment: Then you can see my answer.

Comment: I looks like those are onClick methods that require a certain method signature changing that will cause the app functionality to break.

Comment: Yes, but as per OP's comment its not! Seem little weird to me too. That's why I confirmed it. You can see my comment in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Move all initialization of all `widgets` in `onCreate(...)` of your `Activity`

```
minutos1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutos);//declare it globally at class level
resultado5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vo2max12Resultado);//declare it globally at class level
```

You can create a separate class named `Utils` and create a static method for calculation in Utils class and call that in both `onClick` event(by this way you can call this method from any class)

```
public static String calculate(float minutos2) {
    double calculo2 = 33 + 0.17 * (minutos2 - 1955) / 15;
    String msg1 = String.format("%.2f", calculo2);
    return msg1;
}
```

in `onClick` of those Button do like this

```
public void vo2maxCalculo(View v) {
float minutos2;
String msg = minutos1.getText().toString().trim();
if(msg != null && !msg.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    minutos2 = Float.parseFloat(msg);
else
    minutos2 = 0.00;

String msg1 = Utils.calculate(minutos2);
resultado5.setText(msg1);
}

public void shareIt(View v) {
    float minutos2;
    String msg = minutos1.getText().toString().trim();
    if(msg != null && !msg.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        minutos2 = Float.parseFloat(msg);
    else
        minutos2 = 0.00;

    String msg1 = Utils.calculate(minutos2);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = String.format("The result is:", msg1);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Final Result");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The propper wat is to use global variable ( as mentioned before) and updated this variable inside vo2maxCalculo after it was called.

Another way - you can extract text from resultado5 using `resultado5.getText().toString();

You did not mentioned but you may unsuccesfully tring to implement onClick behaviour? In this case add in layout xml file `android:onClick="vo2maxCalculo"` and `android:onClick="shareIt"`
If those method are in other activities, you should pass intent when create activity or save data in singleTon ( usefull only for big havie single objects, like bitmaps)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with the valuable help of you all the problem is solved and the working code is:

```
String msg1; //Like this

public void vo2maxCalculo(View v) {
float minutos2;
double calculo2;

EditText minutos1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutos);
TextView resultado5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vo2max12Resultado);


minutos2 = Float.parseFloat(minutos1.getText().toString());

calculo2 = 33 + 0.17 * (minutos2 - 1955) / 15;
msg1 = String.format("%.2f", calculo2); //Set it in here like this
resultado5.setText(msg1);
```

}

public void shareIt(View v) {

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

//Can still use it in here as long as the other method got called first
String shareBody = String.format("The result is: %s", msg1);

sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Final Result");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

}

Thanks to everyone that spent a valuable amount of time in helping me solve the problem!